# extJS login window + rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, extjs

I have cotnrol_admin:

```
  def login
    if request.post?
      if params[:full_name] == "mg" && params[:password] == "123"
        data = { :success => 'true', :msg => "Welcome, #{params[:full_name]}"}
        #redirect_to :action => :welcome
        #render :action => :welcome 
      else
        data = { :failure => 'true', :msg => "Username or Password wrong !"}
      end
      render :text => data.to_json, :layout => false
    end
  end
```

I have this login.js

```
var loginForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    baseCls: 'x-plain',
    labelWidth: 75,
    url:'/admin/login',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Login',
        name: 'full_name',
        anchor:'90%'  // anchor width by percentage
    },{
    fieldLabel: 'Password',
    name: 'password',
    inputType: 'password',
    anchor: '90%'  // anchor width by percentage
}],
buttons: [{
    text: 'Login',
    handler: function() {
        loginForm.getForm().submit(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                waitMsg:'Submitting...',

                reset : false,
                success : function() {
                    loginWindow.close();

                },
                failure: function(form, action){Ext.Msg.alert('Error',action.result.text)}
            });
        }
    }]

});

var loginWindow = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Login',
    width: 300,
    height:140,
    closable:false,
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 140,
    layout: 'fit',
    plain:true,
    modal:true,
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px;',
    items: loginForm
});
Ext.onReady(function(){
    loginWindow.show(this);
});
```

So my questions is: everythings work pefectly. But when i press refresh button this login form comes again, how i can avoid this? I think about session. right? but how to integrate session in extJS or rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you though correctly, you need to use session. If you are beginner read about [session management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_management). RoR related session details can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm).

When you login for the first time, if the user provided the correct information.. you need to create a session and store some info into it(for validating the session). When the use hit the URL again, first you need to check if the session is valid or not. If valid, you can simply forward the user to the application home page. Otherwise, the login page is displayed again.